# clojure - using loop and recur with a lazy sequence

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

If I am returning a lazy-seq from a function like this:

```
(letfn [(permutations [s]
              (lazy-seq
               (if (seq (rest s))
                 (apply concat (for [x s]
                                 (map #(cons x %) (permutations (remove #{x} s)))))
                 [s])))])
```

If I use loop recur like below, will the list be eagerly evaluated?

```
(loop [perms (permutations chain)]
       (if (empty? perms)
         (prn "finised")
         (recur (rest perms))))
```

If it is eagerly evaluated, can I use loop..recur to lazily loop over what is returned from the `permutations` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list is lazily evaluated by your loop-recur code.

You can try it out yourself. Let's make `permutations` print something every time it returns a value by adding a `println` call.

```
(defn permutations [s]
  (lazy-seq
   (if (seq (rest s))
     (apply concat (for [x s]
                     (map #(cons x %) (permutations (remove #{x} s)))))
     (do
       (println "returning a value")
       [s]))))
```

When using `loop`, let's also print the values with we're looping over with `(prn (first perms)`.

```
(loop [perms (permutations [1 2 3])]
  (if (empty? perms)
    (prn "finised")
    (do
      (prn (first perms))
      (recur (rest perms)))))
```

Here's what it prints:

```
returning a value
(1 2 3)
returning a value
(1 3 2)
returning a value
(2 1 3)
returning a value
(2 3 1)
returning a value
(3 1 2)
returning a value
(3 2 1)
"finished"
```

As you can see, "returning a value" and the value lines are interlaced. The evaluation of the lazy seq can be forced with `doall`. If you loop over `(doall (permutations [1 2 3]))`, first it prints all the "returning a value" lines and only then the values.